# Evading Mordack in his castle

Tags: kings-quest-v

**In King's Quest 5**, in the final area of **Mordack's castle**, Mordack himself often shows up **seemingly at random** to deliver an **instant Game Over** in the form of Sith Lord-style death grip.  Despite the apparent unpredictability of it all, however, I've heard rumors that there are **actually tells and signs** that can be seen that can allow one to predict and evade him consistently.  **Is this true?  What specifically are all the signs?**

Comment: If memory serves right you can walk out of the room before the game over, not sure though since it has been over a decade since I played KQ5. Good to see some people actually still play point and click adventures :D +1 just for that!!

Comment: @Kevin Actually, I don't, lol.  Game Grumps is doing an LP, and I've watched several other LPs and looked at TVTropes for it as well.  Never touched the game myself.

Comment: Aw well, half a point for trying. Rounded up is still 1 :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about predicting Mordack's appearance, but there are some things that will bring his attention to you, as well as the guardian's:

- lingering in one room too long, besides his library
- playing the organ in the downstairs hallway
- allowing the cat Manannan to run away after seeing you

I don't think he ever appears in the dungeon or the kitchen - they're both below him.

I just replayed the game a while back. Seemed so much simpler than when I first played it!